# Are there any R packages or published code on topic models that account for time?

Tags: r, text-mining, topic-modeling

I am trying to perform topic modeling on a data set of political speeches that spans 2 centuries, and would ideally like to use a topic model that accounts for time, such as Topics over Time (McCallum and Wang 2006) or the Dynamic Topic model (Blei and Lafferty 2006).

However, given that I am not an experienced coder, the help of an R package or some sample code implementing either of these topic models would really help.

Does anyone know if such packages or published code exists for R?

I have searched extensively and have also considered the Structural Topics Model, but I am unsure if this would be the way to go.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you  need Structural Topic Models that can be easily implemented in R package `stm`. [Here](https://me.eui.eu/andrea-de-angelis/blog/structural-topic-models-to-study-political-text-an-application-to-the-five-star-movements-blog/) is an example of implementation of this framework on political data that take time information into account. More detailed knowledge on the package and the algorithm can be found in their vignette.